# how to allow email as well as username to login into account?

Tags: php, session

for a long time i have been using username as only option to log in to my website account but most of the users forget their username so i want to add email and username both as options to login.

here is my code to create a session and log in the user.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9@._\(\)\']#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]);
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9!@._]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]);
$md5password_login = md5($password_login);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1");
//check for their existance
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //count the number of rows returned
if ($userCount == 1) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$id = $row["id"];
}
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
$_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
} else {
echo "Your Username or Password is Incorrect. please try again.";
exit();
}
}
?>
```

How can i add email with username login ?

Note : the teacher who taught me php showed me how to use mysql_query and not the latest version and i know it is being deprecated so i have already changed all my query's, this is an old code.

Comment: both username and email should be unique in your email. After the login form is submitted, check to see if the string contains '@', if it does, check the email address and password, else check the username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give  option on your login form  to select login (radio button) type as username or Email.Then change your query accordingly:

```
 if($logintype=="Username")
    {
    //Current Username query
    }
    else
    {
    //Email Login query
    }
```

or you can use both in query as:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE (username='$user_login' || email='$_POST[user_login]')  AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: no i want to add check email as well as username in mysql_Query but it returns error.

Comment: do the updated version, but make sure your email address field is set as a unique key in the database. Otherwise if someone has 2 accounts with the same address and password they will always be logging into the most recently created one.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. by checking `post data is email or not`

```
$email = $_POST["user_name"];
if (preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
{
 // email query
}
else
{
// username query
}
```